# delphi and android dynamic library

Tags: android, c++11, delphi, shared-libraries

I've compiled a small dynamic Android Arm library (in c ++) just to test how Delphi can interact with it (as a starting point for another real big project) :
Here's my c++ :

```
const char* TestHelloWorld()

    {

    std::string a = "world";
    std::string b = (boost::format("hello: %s") % a).str();    
    char* c = const_cast<char*>(b.c_str());    
    LOGI("%s", c);// using android log ( adb )     
    return c;

    }
```

and here's my Delphi implementation :

```
procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    DocDir, LibFN: string;
    _TestHelloWorld: function() : MarshaledAString; cdecl;   
    hLib: HMODULE;
    begin
     DocDir := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(TPath.GetLibraryPath);
      LibFN:=DocDir + 'libtest-cpp.so';
      hLib := LoadLibrary(PWideChar(LibFN));
      if hLib<>0 then
      begin
       _TestHelloWorld: GetProcAddress(hLib, 'TestHelloWorld');  
        ShowMessage(_TestHelloWorld: );     
      end;
    end;
```

The result in the Android Log :

[image]

The result with delphi :

[image]

So please what's the issue with my delphi code ; is related to using `MarshaledAString` ?

PS : I'm using RAD Studio Tokyo version .

Comment: You don't sow your delphi definition of the c++ function. Also there seems to be a typo in your code on the _TestHelloWorld.

Comment: It is likely an issue of ANSI/UNICODE. Make sure that Delphi and C++ use same character encoding. MarshaledAString is an alias for pointer to AnsiChar. In your C++ code, are char ansi or unicode?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to memory owned by `b` bit `b` is destroyed when the function returns. So you have an invalid pointer and thus undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

I think your C++ char* is a PWideChar (in modern C++Builder), so should be matched to MarshaledString on the Delphi side.

Comment: No. `char*` is an 8 bit type matching `PAnsiChar` or `MarshaledAString`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes. I was conflating it with the behaviour / use of _TCHAR.